# Writing a python program that will pull Yahoo Finance stock quotes into Excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, finance, yahoo-finance

I have created a program that is able to pull monthly stock info from Yahoo Finance and print out a list of the information.  I know my methodology for getting the info isn't the best yet, but the part I am stuck on is taking the stock info and writing it to a csv file.  What I have so far rights each individual character into a csv file.

```
import requests
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
import pandas.io.data

YahooUrl = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='
start_month = 1 - 1
start_day = 1
start_year = 2010

end_month = 12 - 1
end_day = 31
end_year = 2014

Start_ApiMonth = '&a=%s' %(start_month)
Start_ApiDay = '&b=%s' %(start_day)
Start_ApiYear = '&c=%s' %(start_year)

End_ApiMonth = '&d=%s' %(end_month)
End_ApiDay = '&e=%s' %(end_day)
End_ApiYear = '&f=%s' %(end_year)

interval = 'm'

ApiInterval = '&g=%s' %(interval)

ApiStatic = '&ignore=.csv'

Ticker = raw_input("What is the ticker > ")

Website = urlopen(YahooUrl + Ticker + Start_ApiMonth + Start_ApiDay +         Start_ApiYear + End_ApiMonth + End_ApiDay + End_ApiYear + ApiInterval +  ApiStatic)
Info = Website.read()

output = open('output.csv','wb')
wr = csv.writer(output, dialect='excel')
for item in Info:
    wr.writerow(item)
print Info
```

Comment: ```urlopen``` returns a file;ike object. ```read()``` returns a single string - you will need to *parse* that string to split it into the relevant  fields.  You should include an example of ```print(Info)``` - if it is not too long or just a portion of it (to give us an idea of the structure) and try to parse it yourself.

Comment: `pandas` has built-in tools to pull data from Yahoo Finance, see [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance) for an overview. Using the `pandas` API should involve much less manual work on your part.

Answer (score 2):

`read()` returns a string, hence `Info` is a string. Iteration over a string results in iterating over each of the characters that comprise the string:

```
>>> for c in 'abcd':
...     print c
a
b
c
d
```

Therefore your code will write each character to the csv file on its own line.

The data that you are receiving is actually already in CSV format. Here are the first few lines for stock YHOO:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2014-12-01,51.43,51.68,48.290001,50.509998,16328900,50.509998
2014-11-03,46.049999,52.619999,45.740002,51.740002,25212400,51.740002
```

So it should simply be a matter of saving the file:

```
with open('{}.csv'.format(Ticker),'wb') as output:
    output.write(Website.read())
```

This will write the data to a file named with the stock name followed by `.csv` extension, e.g. `YHOO.csv`

---

**Update**

The following code shows how to download and merge data for multiple stocks. The output file now needs an additional field to identify the stock - `Stock ID`. This is inserted as the first CSV field for the header and detail rows. The header is emitted once only.

```
import requests

yahoo_url = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv'
params = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2010, 'd': 11, 'e': 31, 'f': 2014, 'g': 'm', 'ignore': '.csv'}
stock_ids = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'YHOO']
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    header_written = False
    for stock_id in stock_ids:
        params['s'] = stock_id
        r = requests.get(yahoo_url, params=params)
        lines = r.iter_lines()
        header = next(lines)
        if not header_written:
            output.write('Stock ID,{}\n'.format(header))
            header_written = True
        output.writelines('{},{}\n'.format(stock_id, line) for line in lines)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  That worked perfectly! I was curious if there is a way to write multiple stock information into excel.  Say I changed my code to pull in AAPL and GOOG and I wanted it to write into one CSV file.  How would I go about that?